# log4net.dll is giving me problem on WinCE 6.0

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am new to winCE (.net 2.0) programming.
My project is in C# language. A guy before me was using log4net (Runtime version : V1.1.4322, Version 1.2.10.0).  What does those versions means, Am I right V1.1.4322 means it was compiled on .net version 1.1.4322
Now the problem is if I compile it is giving me warning(s):

---

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Data, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes" from Version "1.0.5000.0" [] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SmartDevices\SDK\CompactFramework\2.0\v2.0\WindowsCE\System.Data.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

---

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Xml, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes" from Version "1.0.5000.0" [] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SmartDevices\SDK\CompactFramework\2.0\v2.0\WindowsCE\System.Xml.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

---

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes" from Version "1.0.5000.0" [] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SmartDevices\SDK\CompactFramework\2.0\v2.0\WindowsCE\System.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

---

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.`

---

My application .exe is OK but when I am running WinCE Emulator it is crashing

I have worked with `app.config`, it didn't fix my problem

any suggestions ?

Comment: what is it crashing with, be specific.

Comment: What lead you to believe it was an app.config problem?  What did you change?  What code is actually crashing and what's the exception it crashes with?

Comment: When I start Visual Studio debugger, where it will open Win CE emulator try to load image of WinCE that I just compiled with (with warnings).

Comment: When I start Visual Studio debugger, where it will open Win CE emulator try to load image of WinCE that I just compiled with (with warnings). it gives this error:  
An unexpected error has occurred in MyApp.exe (that is app name)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is you've got references to two different versions of log4net.

Check any referenced assemblies to see if you've got references in those projects. Then confirm the versions of any copies of the file you've got on disk.

It can be a pain to find the offending file; I've found the simplest thing is to find all copies on disk, and just delete *all* copies of the incorrect version. Then see where your project complains and adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you're having *just* a log4net problem.

The assemblies its complaining about are normal CLR assemblies (from the `System` namespace). It almost seems to me that you have references to several .NET 1.1 assemblies but you've got your project set to use .NET 2.0. The IDE is asking you to map the 1.1 assemblies to the 2.0 ones so that your project will know which one it should use at runtime.